# can I use Template literals in javascript for long text which must be single row, and for *readability only* do it multi-line?

Tags: javascript, string, template-literals

for example - I expect to get some single line (or few lines) long text, and I want to test the text correctness.

```
let x = getLongTest();
let y = `firstName: ${firstName},... lastName: ${lastName}...';
x.should.equal(y);
```

now, y is really long, so I want to write it in multi-line for readability.
should I use old string format "...",

or I have any option to use the new form of Template literals with "read-only" line breaks?

Comment: What do you mean by old string format?

Comment: old: " " vs new:` `

Comment: Would concatenating template literals be an option?

Comment: which concatenating type? the " " + " " ?

Comment: actually I got my answer from the duplication link